# Auto calculate UV Tile according to the dimension of our model and texture in 3dsMax

Tags: 3dsmax, uv-mapping

I am using 3dsMax. I have Square 3D model having size 30" X 30" X 30". 
My Wood Texture size is 5" X 5" X 5".

Is there any option in which UV Tile will be automatically get unfold and UV tile to fit repeat the texture 6 times on one face of the model?

Please refer the image for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not really the place for *using* or how to use 3dsmax.

Otherwise in answer to your question, the answer is no.
But you could write up a maxscript (the easiest way) to automatically apply those settings to a uvw map. You could invoke that script

1. from a macoscript
2. automatically when you add a uvwmap to a box

The best place is the autodesk support websites, or scriptspot.com.